# Nginx and Node.js - Utilizing server to fullest

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, proxy, load-balancing

For experimental/learning purposes (lets assume my application has lot of persistent/concurrent traffic), I have a VM running docker. For docker, I have following setup:

[image]

Everything has its own container and communicates with ports. I am trying to simulate two different servers (Nginx), load-balanced by HAProxy.

Now it works all fine and well, but as far as I think, Node is still running in just single thread.

The only configuration Nginx contains is for being reverse proxy to Node (everything else is default). Each Nginx server handles only one domain per server (Node).

- Should I use Node *Cluster* for multi-threaded approach?
- Or (assuming each server has 2 cores) should I create two node instances for each Nginx server and have it load balance? In this approach, I am unsure about how load-balancing would work. If there are two Node instances, load balanced by Nginx (or HAProxy), then it would look something like:

[image]

Now the reason I want Nginx is for static caching and stuff like DDOS protection. Does that really make sense? Or should I just have one Nginx load-balance between all four Node servers without HAProxy (the reason I am bringing in HAProxy is because some research showed it to be faster/more-reliable than Nginx (unconfirmed)).

---

Still new to this. Basically, I want to simulate two servers with two cores each running Node.js, reverse proxied by Nginx for static caching etc., and load-balanced by HAProxy.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer (a while ago, but just updating this post in case it helps someone).

Nginx can run multiple worker processes. So we can just use multiple virtual server blocks to implement this. The current approach I followed with Docker/Nginx/Node is:

- **Nginx server block 1:** This listens to all requests on port 81. And this forwards all those requests to a node instance (lets call it *node1*).
- **Nginx server block 2:** This listens to all requests on port 82. And forwards all of them to another node instance (lets call it *node2*).

In simple words, one server block communicates with node1 and another with node2, where node1 and node2 are two node instances (separate docker containers).

These are then load balanced by HAProxy. Where the server configuration is (in accordance with docker) as follows:

```
server n1 nginx:81
server n2 nginx:82
```

`nginx` is the container name. Nginx currently runs 2 worker processes.
(Add whatever http/tcp checks required, this is just minimal configuration).

Open to suggestions for a better approach.